# fetch problem with axios on mobile request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make axios.post request from my react to node api.
In my PC or Mac it working well, But from my iPhone Chrome or Safari it's not.

The code:

```
    const transport = axios.create({
    origin: "http://localhost:3003",
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
})
```

;

```
transport.post('http://localhost:3001/user/signin', user) 
    .then(res => {
        if(res.status === 200) {
            Cookies.set('user', res.data.token, { expires: 7 });
            const user = {
                fullName: res.data.user.full_name,
                email: res.data.user.email,
                token: res.data.token
            };
            props.signIn(user);
            history.push('/');
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        props.clearPropsFromUser();
    });
```

Someone can help me? thanks

Comment: What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: i think you should change `localhost` to your network ports for it to work on your phone.